# Why GC of JVM collects only those objects that are created by new keyword

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I was reading some article about GC (garbage collector). and there they mentioned that GC of JVMcollects only those objects that are created by new keyword and I wanted to test it by overriding the finalize method and it did the same. Can any one please explain me why JVM do this.

```
public class Test{

    public static Class<Test> main(){

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void finalize(){System.out.println("object is garbage collected");}  
     public static void main(String args[]){  

       Class<Test> obj= Test.main();  

       Test t1 = new Test();
       Test t2 = new Test();

       t1 = null;
       t2 = null;
       obj = null;

       System.gc();  
     } 
}
```

Hear I have three objects i.e. obj, t1 and t2.

t1 and t2 are object created with new keyword but obj calling some method (if you want you can keep something else). later all three objects will be nullified and requesting for GC to garbage collect.

when I execute this program finalize method called for two times only (It require to execute two to three times to see the out put because nether finalize nor GC is garneted).

Comment: Where did you read this? Garbage collection can collect all objects that are no longer referenced. Of course, unless you use reflection, all objects will have been created by a `new` keyword (directly or indirectly).

Comment: `obj` is not an Object at all. It is `null`. That it was returned from a function call is immaterial. No finalizer (or any other method) can or will be invoked on `null`.

Comment: Also note that `Class<Test>` is different from `Test`. You can have an instance of `Class<Test>` without an instance of `Test`.

Comment: I red it in http://www.javatpoint.com/Garbage-Collection

Comment: @Thilo just I wanted have another object which have some reference and get nullified, so that GC should collect the memory used by that variable

Comment: @RajeshHatwar The site doesn't look very reliable. You should stick to official Oracle documentation and tutorials, and well known resources (such as StackOverflow).

Comment: A `null` does not use up any heap memory, so there is nothing to be garbage collected. If you want to have another object, you need to create another object. If you don't want to use `new`, you could do `Integer.valueOf(12345)` (but of course, that just hides away the `new`), or `String.class.newInstance()`.

Comment: The quote in question ("Note: The Garbage collector of JVM collects only those objects that are created by new keyword. So if you have created any object without new, you can use finalize method to perform cleanup processing (destroying remaining objects).") is non-sense.

Comment: Suppose, we think that the site is not correct..! Let we have another object which have an object reference created other than new keyword. Then finalize should execute for three times when GC executes..?.

Comment: Using "String.class.newInstance();" still finalize executes two times only.

Comment: So? `finalize()` isn't guaranteed to execute at all.

Comment: You cannot override the finalizer for `String` anyway.

Comment: I suspect the intended meaning was for non-Object things that still consume resources, such as dynamically defined classes (not instances of objects, but rather the use of java.lang.ClassLoader), or possibly non-Java resources such as file handles, network connections, and OS-level non-managed memory allocations within wrapper objects, etc.  Most Java implementations typically require cleanup of those.  However, even if that is the case, it isn't likely to be a very good resource if it doesn't spell that out carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are only collected when they are no longer referenced.

`null` references are never collected as there is no object to collect.

It doesn't matter how an Object is created, they can be GC-ed however objects which are created via other means such as Classes and String literals tend to have a longer lifecycle, but they follow the same rules all objects follow.

Answer (score 0):

whatever `new` keyword or `Class.newInstance()` or other way to create an object,it will consume heap memory.
In this case, `obj` is null, so, it doesn't consume any heap memory,it's will not execute `finalize`.

if you want to execute three times,try this: `Test.class.newInstance()`

Hope to help you.